# Rails daily calendar with html table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to make a daily calendar with the following setup:

[image]

The professionals I'm listing like this:

```
- professionals.each do |professional|
  = professional.name
```

In my Agenda class I have the following setup:

```
class Agenda < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :professionals
  has_many :services
  has_many :costumers
end
```

I'd like to list each professional with its respective scheduling, the professionals must be in the left side and their scheduling in the right side, like the picture.

How to list the professionals in the left side and their scheduling in the right side ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I edited the question, please take a look :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to implement the required functionality would be to use the [Calendar Helper gem](https://github.com/topfunky/calendar_helper) to generate the calendar, and populate the details appropriately based on the param indicating which professional is selected.